# scp with expect module not working

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have written the following program for automating scp command in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn scp hscpe@9.126.134.54:/home/hscpe/output.txt imt
set pass "jujsa32s"
expect {
        password: {send "$pass\r"; exp_continue
     }
```

But the file transfer is not happening. Normally on console if I tried the same scp command its working fine. Can anyone figure out the problem

Thanks in advance!!..

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH):

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('hscpe@9.126.134.54', password => 'jujsa32s');
$ssh->scp_get('/home/hscpe/output.txt', 'imt/output.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using expect for your password.
I think you should use [expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) for this task. The environment used when running a perl script might miss parts to run expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "sshpass" in a bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p "password" scp -r user@example.com:/some/remote/path /some/local/path
```